# Why is group theory axiomatized with operations?

Tags: group-theory

The notion of 'operation' seems so arbitrary. In textbooks on group theory, and for example on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_(mathematics)#Definition), they define the group multiplication operation $\circ$ as having properties of:

1. Closure: For all $a, b\in G$, the result of the operation, $a\circ b$, is also in $G$.
2. Associativity: For all $a, b, c\in G$, $(a\circ b)\circ c = a\circ (b\circ c)$.
3. Identity element: There exists an element $e \in G$ such that, for every element $a \in G$, the equation $e\circ a = a\circ e = a$ holds.
4. Inverse element: For each $a \in G$, there exists an element $b \in G$, such that $a \circ b = b \circ a = e$, where e is the identity element.

> I do not understand why axiom (1) is used.

Often, axiom (1) is replaced by defining a function
$$
\circ:G\times G \rightarrow G
$$
and stating that axioms (2)-(4) hold for this binary function.

Here the closure axiom becomes unnecessary, but more importantly, it is more clear *what an operation is,* and *why the properties of associativity and commutativity are actually special*. Furthermore, students will be more careful when doing proofs, because they know that the properties they are using are not valid for ordinary functions.

I'm not questioning the correctness of group theory, but this is something I've wondered about for a while.

Comment: Definitions of group do not usually talk about "closure".

Comment: I think the primary reason is the belief - correct or not - that speaking in terms of "binary operations" is clearer for students with no prior experience than jumping right into maps $G\times G\rightarrow G$. The point is that "binary operation" is a phrase that they've (probably) heard before, and may be able to absorb more quickly than general function notation. I'm not sure whether this is right, but I think that's likely a motivation (there may also be historical precedent, I'm not sure how the original definition of an abstract group was phrased).

Comment: You said "bla bla bla", but what are the axioms that you're not understanding?

Comment: @NoahSchweber Why is a student learning group theory if they don't know what a function is? Function is the basis of all of abstract math; one should not delve into abstract math without at least an operational understanding of the concepts of function and set.

Comment: @extremeaxe5 Groups aren't particularly abstract. Many concrete examples can be and are introduced to (some) middle schoolers, such as the additive and multiplicative groups of the integers mod $n$ for some $n\in\Bbb{Z}$. These can be introduced without introducing set theory. Also some people know what functions are but wouldn't have as good intuition for $*:G\times G\to G$ compared to $*$ is a binary operation on $G$. E.g. physics majors or something.

Comment: This may help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2377598/is-it-always-possible-to-create-a-intuition-for-abstract-algebra-theorems/2377632#2377632

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Define "usually". Wikipedia defines a group using 4 axioms, one of which is "closure". When I was first taught group theory the definition used closure. In the second course the lecturer discussed the differences between the 4-axiom closure definition and the 3-axiom definition where closure is folded into the phrase "binary operation". I still remember him discussing this many years later, and I remember at the time the implication that they discussed the different definitions in the staff room......

Comment: (On a related note, I do not understand the 4 close votes.)

Comment: @user1729 Picking a few introductory textbooks at random, I find Cohn *Algebra volume 1*, Lang *Algebra*, Dummit/Foote *Abstract Algebra*, all define a group as a set with a binary operation with the usual properties. None talk about "closure". The OP is tilting at a straw man.

Comment: The OP is *not* "tilting at a straw man". Sure, the 3 books you found don't use this definition. However, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_(mathematics)), [ProofWiki](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Group_Axioms), [WolframMathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Group.html), the [Open University](http://www.open.edu/openlearn/ocw/pluginfile.php/622484/mod_resource/content/1/m208_3_section3.pdf), [Queen Mary University of London](http://www.maths.qmul.ac.uk/~pjc/notes/gt.pdf), and [Berkeley](https://math.berkeley.edu/~gmelvin/math113su14/math113su14notes_online.pdf) all do.

Comment: (I am not claiming that this "4-axiom" definition is standard. However, it *is* used in places. To dismiss it because you have never come across it before is naïve.)

Comment: "...and why the properties of associativity and commutativity are actually special....": I'd definitely not put at the same level the two properties: the former is fundamental, the latter purely ancillary and really "special".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These closure properties are explicitly stated because it is important for subgroups. Indeed, if $H$ is a subgroup of $G,\times$ one needs that $h\times h'\in H$. In this sense the operation is closed. In other words, one needs that $\text{im}(\times_{\mid H\times H})\subseteq H$. It easier to say that $H$ is closed.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps one reason is the "binary operation" definition is completely abstract, however it is helpful to be concrete in a first course in group theory. For example, suppose I want to show that all real-valued invertible $n\times n$ matrices, denoted $GL_n(\mathbb{R})\subset M_n(\mathbb{R})$, form a group. Then what I have to do is think about the function $$\circ: GL_n(\mathbb{R})\times GL_n(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow M_n(\mathbb{R})$$ and show that the image of this function is precisely $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$; that is, show closure. Here, $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ is not a group so we are not talking about subgroups of groups but something *slightly* more complicated.