# How do I prove that $S=${$0,10,20$} is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z_{30}}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

Prove that  $S=${$0,10,20$} is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z_{30}}$.

I would also like to know how to show that $\mathbb{Z_{30}}$ it's a group.

I know of theory that $\mathbb{Z_{n}}$ it's an abelian group but I do not understand why it is.

I'm having a very difficult time with such problems and would be very thankful to anyone who would take the time to slowly explain how does one even begin to take a stab at answering such a question. Thank you for your help.

Comment: "I know of theory that $\mathbb{Z_{n}}$ it's an abelian group but I do not understand why it is." If this is not obvious to you, then you need to take a good look at the definition of a group, and familiarise yourself with the addition operation of $\Bbb Z_n$ (possibly by picking an $n$, then just add random elements of $\Bbb Z_n$ together) until it is obvious, because it's not going to get easier than that.

Comment: @Arthur Well there's always the trivial group :P (point stands though.. $\Bbb Z_n$ is the next simplest set of examples).

Comment: As for showing $\{0,10,20\}$ is a subgroup of $\Bbb Z_{30}$... this can be done by brute force.  First show that the addition of any two elements of $S$ results in an element of $S$ (*using the same type of addition one would use in $\Bbb Z_{30}$*), show that there is an additive identity in $S$, and show that each element in $S$ has an additive inverse in $S$.  For example, $10+20=0$ so we know $20$ is the additive inverse of $10$ in this context.  (*$S$ acts very similarly to $\Bbb Z_3$, for good reason too that you may learn more about later in your studies*)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Prove that S is a subgroup of $\Bbb Z_{30}$.*

To do this - we apply the [subgroup test](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Two-Step_Subgroup_Test):

- Closure. Take two elements from $S$. Then, is it true that the addition of these two elements are in $S$? Well, yes: $$0+10=10,\quad 0+20=20,\quad 10+20=0,$$ $$0+0=0,\quad 10+10=20,\quad 20+10=0.$$
- Identity. Is the identity element of $\Bbb Z_{30}$ present in $S$? Yes, $0$ is in $S$.
- Inverse. Given any element of $S$ - is its inverse in it also? Well, yes: $$0^{-1}=0,\quad 10^{-1}=20,\quad 20^{-1}=10.$$

So, $S$ is a subgroup of $\Bbb Z_{30}$.

*I would also like to know how to show that $\Bbb Z_{30}$ is a group.*

To do this - we must check the [group axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_(mathematics)#Definition) are satisfied for $\Bbb Z_{30}$:

- We find that closure and assosciativity will be apparent since these operations are closed when we add integers in general.
- The identity element in $\Bbb Z_{30}$ is $0$.
- For inverses, given any element in $\Bbb Z_{30}$, you should be able to write the corresponding number that, upon addition, gives the identity element $0$. For example, the inverse of $11$ is $19$ since $11+19=0$.

*I know of theory that $\Bbb Z_n$ it's an abelian group but I do not understand why it is.*

Recall that an abelian group is a group $G$ where $g\circ h=h\circ g$ for all $g,h\in G$ for some binary operation $\circ$. So, in the case of $\Bbb Z_{30
}$ say, does the relation $g+h=h+g$ hold for all $g,h\in\Bbb Z_{30}$?

---

Do feel free to let me know if this is still confusing or you have any further queries.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, @thesmallprint. It is very complete and thank you for your kindness too. I ask you some more questions that I do not understand well: a) When you study if S is subgroup of $Z_{30}$ you verify that, for example, for two elements of S, the sum of them is in $Z_{30}$ . If the result were in $Z_{30}$  but it isn't in S then would the step be verified or not? b) why the inverse of $10^{−1}$ is 20 and the inverse of $20^{−1}$ is 10? c) How can we demonstrate in a general way that for any $Z_{30}$ element we can find another one that is its inverse?

Comment: (a) Having read over my answer - I notice that I made a typo. Indeed in the closure part of the subgroup test, I was meant to write "the addition of two elements is in S" and not $\Bbb Z_{30}$. I have since amended it to the correct version. Apologies for any confusion. (b) Recall that an inverse is an element $a$ such that $g\circ a=a\circ g=e$ where $e$ is the identity element. Since for $\Bbb Z_{30}$ the identity is $0$ it follows that, for $10$ say, $a$ comes from solving $10+a=0$. (c) Once you start writing out a few inverses of some elements, a pattern should emerge.

Comment: I get it. thank you very much for the help and for your time!

Comment: The pleasure is all mine!

Comment: In order to show $S$, is a subgroup you can also just compute : $xy^{-1}$. If for all $x,y \in S$ we have : $xy^{-1} \in S$, then $S$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_{30}$

Comment: Your calculations for the closure are incomplete. For instance, you forgot to square the elements with respect to the operation.

Comment: Ah yes, of course. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: @Thinking $0, 10  \in S$  but $ 0+(-10)=-10$ is't in $S$ I am doing something wrong? because with that test S would not be subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_{30}$

Comment: @Thinking  Is the following example correct for the method you enunciated to see if S is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_{30}$ ?  $0,10 \in S$  then $0+(−10)=0+20=20 \in S$

Comment: @Ayesca You are missing some cases.

Comment: $0+(−0)=0+0=0 \in S ; 10+(−0)=10+0=10 \in S ; 20+(−0)=20+0=0 \in S ; 20+(−10)=20+20=10 \in S ; 10+(-10)=10+20=0  \in S ; 20+(−20)=20+10=0 \in S ;0+(−10)=0+20=20 \in S ; 0+(−20)=0+10=10 \in S ; 10+(−20)=10+10=20 \in S$ Are these all? Are they well resolved? @Thinking

Comment: @Ayesca Yes this is perfect !

Comment: great! thank you very much! @Thinking

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you start by writing out the addition tables for $\mathbb{Z}_n$ for some small values of $n$. See that the group axioms are satisfied. (Checking associativity for all the combinations would be tedious - just do a few.) Then you will have a better understanding of those groups, and of the proof that they are groups. Then find all the subgroups of those groups, by working with the tables. You should be able to do this reasonably quickly for all $n \le 8$. When you're done you'll be able to answer your question about $\mathbb{Z}_{30}$ in one or two lines.

In general, the way to understand theorems is by understanding many examples. See [Is it always possible to create a intuition for abstract algebra theorems?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2377598/is-it-always-possible-to-create-a-intuition-for-abstract-algebra-theorems/2377632#2377632)

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion, I'm going to listen to you and hope to understand the concepts of algebraic structures, like verifying that something is a body, a group ...

Answer (score 1):

For the first part of you question, notice that $S$ contains only three elements: you can build the addition table for $S$ and verify that $S$ is closed with respect to it:

$0$ is the neutral element,

$10+10=20$,

$10+20=0$,

$20+20=10$.